# Error while connecting to kinect v2

Tags: kinect

I am trying to connect Kinect v2 sensor to my PC.while running the kinect configuration verifier i am getting below error in Graphic processor.
see attached screenshot.
[image: Kinect V2 Configuration Verifier]

Comment: do you have Direct X on your computer ?

Comment: yes, i have checked my computer , the directx version is 11.

Comment: What is the graphics card of your computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Nvidia NVS 300 specs](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-nvs-300-us.html), it is not DX11 capable. It says "Microsoft DirectX 10.1". So no luck with the Microsoft SDK.

You'd have to get a different graphics card to use the Kinect v2 with the Microsoft SDK.

Or you might want to check out [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2), an open source Kinect2 driver, which has lower hardware requirements. But it only provides raw data, no advanced features like skeleton tracking.

Comment: ok thank you..what is the solution?? do i have to change my graphics card.

Comment: Yeah, get a different graphics card, one that supports DX11. Or, as I said, try libfreenect2, an open source alternative to the Microsoft SDK.